# How to send Journey Builder email tracking data from Marketing Cloud to Sales Cloud through v5 Connector?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have integrated Sales & Marketing Clouds using v5 connector. I am able to fetch reports/leads/contacts from SC to MC and using Journey Builder in MC to send emails, Once the email has sent, the tracking data is not appearing at Sales Cloud.

If I use Automation Studio then Tracking Data populates at SC.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Journey Builder sends cannot be currently captured in SalesCloud because Journey builder cannot include Salesforce data extensions as their event source (even if SFDC ID is used as the Subscriber Key). The product team at Marketing Cloud, I believe, is working on facilitating this in the next release with Data Stream features.

Comment: gkpawar, are you aware of any recent updates that have addressed this?   I see now there is a 'Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud' option on JB Email Activities.

Comment: Any recent update?